# Need to color five different cells to the right of a cell if a condition is met for a specific range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so any help is greatly appreciated.  For a specific range of cells, I have if statements.  So for **A25:A31** if `cells.value = 1` then I want cells **(x,4) (x,7) (x,10) (x,13)** in that same row that the condition is met to all have the same background color.  I have tried to offset but it only works for one offset selection not multiple.  Here is my code:

```
Set Rng1 = Range("A25:A31")
Set Rng2 = Range("B25:B31")
For Each cell In Rng1
    If cell.Value = "1" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color
    If cell.Value = "2" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color
    If cell.Value = "3" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color
    If cell.Value = "4" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color
    If cell.Value = "5" Then cell.Offset(0, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
Next Cell
```

So I basically want something that will do the following:

```
If cell.Value = "1" Then cell.Offset(0, 1 & 4 & 7 & 10).Cells.Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color
```

so instead of changing only the offset one column over it also changes the cell to the right, and the cell four over, and the cell seven over etc..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Based on your problem description, you could use conditional formatting rather than VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim C As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'change this for the name of your sheet
        For Each C In .Range("A25:A31")
            If C = 1 Then
                Union(C, .Cells(C.Row, 4), .Cells(C.Row, 7), .Cells(C.Row, 10), .Cells(C.Row, 13)).Interior.Color = 2 'whatever colour you need
            End If
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it help. Mark it as answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim v 
Set Rng1 = Range("A25:A31")
Set Rng2 = Range("B25:B31")

For Each cell In Rng1.Cells
    v = cell.Value

    Select Case v
        Case 1,2,3,4,5: 
            cell.EntireRow.Range("D1,G1,J1,M1").Interior.Color = _
                  Range("B11").Offset(v, 0).Interior.Color
    End Select

Next Cell
```

Note the `Range()` is *relative to EntireRow*, so as written it will always operate on that row.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @JohnColeman commented, but if you want vba, I think this is is what you are looking for. But @TimWilliams is more advanced.

```
Sub ColorCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A25:A31")
        If cel.Value = 1 Then
            cel.Resize(, 2).Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 6).Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 9).Interior.Color = Range("B12").Interior.Color

        ElseIf cel.Value = 2 Then
            cel.Resize(, 2).Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 4).Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 9).Interior.Color = Range("B13").Interior.Color

        ElseIf cel.Value = 3 Then
            cel.Resize(, 2).Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 6).Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 9).Interior.Color = Range("B14").Interior.Color

        ElseIf cel.Value = 4 Then
            cel.Resize(, 2).Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 6).Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 9).Interior.Color = Range("B15").Interior.Color

        ElseIf cel.Value = 5 Then
            cel.Resize(, 2).Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 6).Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
            cel.Offset(, 9).Interior.Color = Range("B16").Interior.Color
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```